# React hooks: Can't update state inside function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-hooks

I'm new to React and am trying to figure out how to make a phonebook. I've gotten quite far but I'm having an issue I can't solve. I'm using React Hooks.

Everything works fine, except for when I call the `setNewNumber('')` and `setNewName('')` functions at the end of `addPerson()`, just before the `filteredEntries` const. 
I want to reset the input fields in the form to empty strings (`''`) once the other code inside `addPerson()` is done running, but it seems like the two functions are never called since the value for `newName` and `newNumber` don't change to `''` (instead they keep the values the user added). However, my other useState functions (`setPersons()` and `setFilteredPersons()`) work inside `addPerson()`...

I've tried reading the documentation and asking around but haven't found a solution. I'd be very grateful for any clues/help!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Person from './components/Person'

const App = () => {
  const [ persons, setPersons ] = useState([
    { name: 'Cat', number: '111' },
    { name: 'Dog', number: '222' },
    { name: 'Horse', number: '333' },
    { name: 'Owl', number: '444' }
  ]) 
  const [filteredPersons, setFilteredPersons] = useState([...persons])
  const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')
  const [ newNumber, setNewNumber ] = useState('')

  const addPerson = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    const createPerson = () => {
      const personObject = {
        name: newName,
        number: newNumber,
      }
      setPersons([...persons, personObject])
      setFilteredPersons([...persons, personObject]) //varför går det inte att bara köra [...persons?]
    }

    const upperCaseNewName = newName.toUpperCase()
    let doubleName
    persons.map(person => {
      const upperCasePerson = person.name.toUpperCase()
      if(upperCaseNewName === upperCasePerson) {
        doubleName = upperCasePerson
      }
      return doubleName
    })

    if (doubleName === undefined) {
      createPerson()
    } else if(doubleName === upperCaseNewName) {
      alert(`${newName} is already in the phonebook`)
    }

    setNewName('')
    setNewNumber('')
  }

  const filterEntries = event => {
      let filtered = persons.filter(person => {
        return person.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(event.target.value.toUpperCase()) !== -1
      })
    setFilteredPersons(filtered)
  }

  const renderPersons = () => filteredPersons.map(person =>
    <Person key={person.name} name={person.name} number={person.number}/>
  )

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <p>Filter entries:</p> <input onChange={(event) => filterEntries(event)}/>
      <form>
        <div>
          name: <input onChange={(event) => setNewName(event.target.value)}/>
          <br/>
          phone: <input onChange={(event) => setNewNumber(event.target.value)}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" onClick={addPerson}>add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      {renderPersons()}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

The person component at the top just contains this code:

```
import React from 'react'

const Person = (props) => {
    return(
        <>
        <p>{props.name} {props.number}</p>
        </>
    )
}

export default Person
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your components are not actually tied to your state values. You need them to be "controlled." Check out the docs for more examples :)

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

`<input value={newName} onChange={event => setNewName(event.target.value)} />`

Answer (score 2):

The reset is working correctly. What you forgot to do is add the `value` to each input. Without the `value` attribute the input is considered an [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). By the sounds of it, you're looking to [control](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) the value via code.

Change

```
<div>
  name: <input onChange={event => setNewName(event.target.value)} />
  <br />
  phone: <input onChange={event => setNewNumber(event.target.value)} />
</div>
```

to

```
<div>
  name: <input value={newName} onChange={event => setNewName(event.target.value)} />
  <br />
  phone: <input value={newNumber} onChange={event => setNewNumber(event.target.value)} />
</div>
```

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-tree-6hl45)

Answer (score 1):

You have missed adding `value` attribute to `input` and thus your component is not the "Controlled" component.

You can read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

Changes needed

```
<input
   value={newName}
   onChange={event => setNewName(event.target.value)}
/>
<br />
phone:
<input
   value={newNumber}
   onChange={event => setNewNumber(event.target.value)}
/>
```

Codesandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-frog-ecp98

Hope this Helps!